# Using cloudformation, I want to give default security group and SSH security group as the security group of the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am using cloudformation to build the infrastructure.

I want to give default security group and SSH security group as the security group of the instance.

There are Network.yaml, Security.yaml, Application.yaml files.

This is part of Network.yaml.

```
SampleVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: sample-vpc
```

This is part of Security.yaml.

```
Resources:
 BastionSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
   GroupName: sample-sg-bastion
   GroupDescription: for bastion
   VpcId: !ImportValue vpc-id
   SecurityGroupIngress:
   - CidrIp: 10.10.10.10/32
     FromPort: 22
     IpProtocol: tcp
     ToPort: 22
   Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: sample-sg-bastion
Outputs:
  BastionSecurityGroup:
    Description: The Security Group for bastion instance
    Value: !Ref BastionSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: Bastion-sg-id
```

This is part of Application.yaml.

```
Resources:
  BastionEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      #DisableApiTermination: 
      ImageId: !FindInMap [AWSRegionAMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', HVM64]
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      #Monitoring: true|false
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          SubnetId: !ImportValue pubsubnet-01a-id
          DeviceIndex: 0
          GroupSet:
           - !ImportValue Bastion-sg-id
           - ###I want to set DefaultSecurityGroup###
      UserData: !Base64 |
        #!/bin/bash -ex
        # put your script here
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: sample-ec2-bastion
```

What should I do if I want to attach a default security group to an instance?

##########    Modified     ############

It worked well!! I appreciate Allan's support.

I added this code to Network.yaml.

```
DefaultNetworkSG:
    Value:
     !GetAtt SampleVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
    Export:
      Name: default-sg-id
```

I added this code to Application.yaml.

```
  NetworkInterfaces:
    - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
      SubnetId: !ImportValue pubsubnet-01a-id
      DeviceIndex: 0
      GroupSet:
       - !ImportValue Bastion-sg-id
       - !ImportValue default-sg-id
```

Comment: Thank you . However I already wote Outputs section.

Comment: Are you referring to the VPC's default security group? @Yan i've updated the answer to reference the network's default SG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the security group's ID in the list of attached SGs on the EC2's definition, you can do this by exporting the ID of the security group from the `security.yaml` and importing it from the `application.yaml`

Network.yaml

```yaml
  SampleVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: sample-vpc
Outputs:
  DefaultNetworkSG:
    Value:
     !GetAtt SampleVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
```

Security.yaml

```yaml
Outputs:
  BastionSecurityGroupID:
    Value:
      Ref: BastionSecurityGroup
```

Application.yaml

```yaml
  BastionEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      SecurityGroupIds:
      - !ImportValue: BastionSecurityGroupID
      - !ImportValue: DefaultNetworkSG
```

Comment: It was very helpful！！It works with your code.
Thank you.

When I use cloudformation, I think I want to design with architecture.

If possible, I’d like to controll DefaultSecurityGroup in Security.yaml instead of in Network.yaml.

If you like, Do you have a good idea?

Comment: How it works is that any CloudFormation resource has exported set of values post-provisioning. If the VPC is provisioned in the Network.yaml, there's no way it could live in the Security.Yaml coz its a default and bounded member of the VPC in the Network.yaml

Comment: Thank you for telling me how it works.
I could understand the members of VPC (Subnet, DefaultSecurityGroup etc) in Cloudformation.